# Why is Odoo called 'Odoo'?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-12

Does anyone know:

What does the word **Odoo** stands for?

If it is not an abbreviation, then what does **Odoo** means?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming related problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: The history of a product... sometimes has enormous relevance to understand why we are the present stage (in that product)... why some arguable decisions were made... and even try to get a glimpse of the future... the NAME is part of the history,,, I vote to leave the question...

Comment: @Tintumon M The word Odoo is the acronym of On Demand Open Object

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't really mean anything, but it could be said to be an acronym for: On Demand Open Object. It's just the new name for OpenERP, which they didn't like.

For reference: [odoo.com](https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/help-1/question/what-does-odoo-stand-for-52556)

Comment: In fact, they changed the old name, OpenERP, to Odoo, because the company did a research and the result was that companies which have more 'o' in their trade names, are more successful in live (Google, Yahoo!, Facebook, etc...). It sounds very weird but this is what Odoo staff said to explain it.

Comment: Haha fun fact! It never occured to me that the 'big names' all have double o in their names.

Comment: Oopple? Mooc? I'll suggest these to Tim Cook

Comment: @forvas absolutely correct

Comment: @DarylVanSittert Apple and Mac doesn't have it, but Tim Cook has 2 'o' in his name :)

Comment: @MouTio I'm surprised the [iPood](https://www.campsaver.com/sea-to-summit-ipood-pocket-trowel.html) didn't become a global phenomenon.

Comment: @Guinn The word Odoo is the acronym of On Demand Open Object

Answer (score 1):

Its Just a name they chose it because odoo provides more than OpenErp for example Web site modules